# keras soft multiplexer layer

Tags: neural-network, keras

I am new to Keras (and NN) and my question might be simple. Nevertheless, I cannot figure out how to implement the following layer in Keras:

It should have 3 inputs: 2D, 0D, 0D (matrix, scalar, scalar).

The layer should return the element of the first argument at the place defined by the second and the third arguments. Thus, if the input is (m, i, j) it should return m[i, j]. If pair (i, j) "hits between elements" (for example i = 2.5 and j = 3.7) it should return linear approximation of the elements around the point defined by (i, j).

The function is differentiable (at least enough differentiable for Keras) against elements of m, i and j so it should be fine to define an NN layer.

Comment: Could you detail this a little? Do any of these inputs come in batches? NN's are commonly used with many data "samples". Normally, each sample would have its own m, i and j. If you had 10000 samples, for instance, you'd have 10000 m, 10000 i and 10000 j. Is that true in your case? If not, please tell us which ones come in batches and which are in fact a unique value.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, for your question. In my design 2D input (matrix m) is the output of another layer, while 0D, 0D inputs (scalars i, j) are coming from the data (I also consider a design when they come as outputs from other layers). I think, I could replace 0D, 0D input with the precomputed 2D input of proper weights and just use multiplication, but such approach 1. looks ugly, 2. probably less efficient, and 3. is not extendable when i, j are outputs of another layer. Answering to your question, yes all data can come in batches.

Comment: I was really looking for something like this, and you inspired me to find the ways to go. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following function, that we'll pass to a `Lambda` layer:

```
from keras.layers import *
import keras.backend as K
from keras.models import Model

import tensorflow as tf

def getValue(x):

    #x is a group with 3 tensors here. m, i and j
    m = x[0]
    i = x[1]
    j = x[2] 

    #let's take the i and j as integers around the actual point:
    #as well as the distances between them and the float indices
    lowI, distI = getLowIndexAndDistance(i)
    lowJ, distJ = getLowIndexAndDistance(j)

    #higher indices
    highI = lowI + 1 
    highJ = lowJ + 1 
        #in the special case when these high values are exatly equal to the 
        #unrounded ones, the distance below will be 0 and this index will be discarded

    #special case when i or j is exactly the maximum index
    mShape = K.shape(m)
    highI = highI - K.cast(K.equal(highI,mShape[1]),'int32')
    highJ = highJ - K.cast(K.equal(highJ,mShape[2]),'int32')


    #interpolations  
    valILeft = getInterpolated(getValueFromM(m,lowI,lowJ),
                               getValueFromM(m,highI,lowJ), 
                               distI)
    valIRight = getInterpolated(getValueFromM(m,lowI,highJ), 
                                getValueFromM(m,highI,highJ),
                                distI)   

    return getInterpolated(valILeft,valIRight,distJ)


#function to get the index rounded down
    #unfortunately I couldn't find K.floor() or a similar function
def getLowIndexAndDistance(i):

    #getting the closest round number 
    roundI = K.round(i) 

    #comparisons to check wheter the rounded index is greater than i
    isGreater = K.cast(K.greater(roundI,i),K.floatx())
        #1 if true, 0 if false

    #if greater, let's take one number below:
    lowI = roundI - isGreater 

    #returns the integer lowI and the distance between i and lowI
    return K.cast(lowI,'int32'), i - lowI




#function to get interpolated values
def getInterpolated(val1, val2, distanceFromLowI):

    valRange = val2 - val1
    #span = 1

    return val1 + (valRange * distanceFromLowI)


def getEntireIndexMatrix(i,j):

    batchIndex = K.ones_like(i)
    batchIndex = K.cumsum(batchIndex) - 1 #equivalent to range(batch)

    #warning, i and j must be (?,1), if they're reduced, the results will be weird. 
    return K.stack([batchIndex,i,j],axis=-1) 

        #this is a matrix of indices from which to get values in m
        #the first element in the last axis is the batch index   
        #the second element is I
        #the third is J


def getValueFromM(m, i, j):

    indexMatrix = getEntireIndexMatrix(i,j)

    #tensorflow is an easy solution kere. Keras doesn't have this available,
    #but there may be a workaround using K.gather 3 times, one for each dimension
    return tf.gather_nd(m, indexMatrix)
```

**Testing this in a very basic model**:

```
m = Input((5,5))
i = Input((1,))
j = Input((1,))

out = Lambda(getValue, output_shape=(1,))([m,i,j])

model = Model([m,i,j],out)

mVals = np.asarray(range(75)).reshape((3,5,5))
#iVals = np.asarray([[4],[2.3],[4]]) #for special cases
#jVals = np.asarray([[4],[4],[1.7]]) #for special cases
iVals = np.random.uniform(0,4,(3,1)) #for all cases
jVals = np.random.uniform(0,4,(3,1)) #for all cases

print(mVals)
print(iVals)
print(jVals)

print(model.predict([mVals,iVals,jVals]))
```

Comment: It is a rather complex solution, but probably it is unavoidable. After learning Keras backend functions I finally got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The following equation might simplify the code a bit: floor(x) = -round(0.5-x)